# How to write chained inequalities (a <= b <= c) in if functions

Tags: r, if-statement, inequality, inequalities

How can you write the following in if functions in R

Supposing you have X ranging from 121 to 212 and Y ranges from 122 to 212, how can you write an if function to represents something like:

if 121 <= X <= 212 and 122 <= Y <= 212; then do something. I am trying to write it in such as way that any number outside the range will show an error message.

Answer (score 2):

```
X = 15
Y = 25

f = function(X,Y) {
  if ((X >= 10 && X <= 20) && (Y >= 20 && Y <= 30)) {
    print("in range")
  }else{
    print("out of range")
  }
}

f(X = 15, Y = 25)
```

Comment: I'm a little surprised this has lasted this long without this note: the use of `&` here is incorrect on two counts: if `X` or `Y` are ever length other than 1, this will warn about length (and not give you want you expect); and it is bypassing short-circuit evaluation. Replace both of those `&` with `&&` and it's more correct. (The use of `&` is correct if it is wrapped in `any` or `all` or some aggregation. It won't warn if the length is guaranteed to be 1, but there's still the short-circuit omission.)

Comment: I've suggested an edit that reflects that change, I hope that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <- function(set.1, set.2, X, Y){
  if( (min(set.1) <= X & X <= max(set.1)) & (min(set.2) <= Y & Y <= max(set.2))){
    # Then do something
  }
}
```

Basically do something like this.